# Django project deployment: cannot load static files

Tags: django, nginx, static, gunicorn

I'm deploying a Django project using:

- virtualenv
- nginx
- gunicorn

following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps

---

My configuration

**django settings**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/esmart2**

```
GNU nano 2.0.9                 File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/esmart2

server {
    server_name 192.168.30.17;
    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /new_esmart/esmart2/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

**Running**

```
(esmart_env) [root@eprssrv09 esmart2]# /new_esmart/esmart_env/bin/gunicorn --bind 192.168.30.17:8001 esmart2.wsgi:application
```

**My Django project is running but:**

```
Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css
```

**Any advice?**

---

**UPDATE 1**
I think that nginx settings are been avoided:

deleting any reference in 'sites-enabled' folder, django project runs and the problem concerning static files remain.

**UPDATE 2**
if in Django settings `debug=True` I get

```
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
```

Comment: Did you read the static documentation? What are your STATIC* settings? Did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've edited my question with django static settings, I've run collectstatic and all static files are in /new_esmart/esmart2/static/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I solved BUT I don't think is the better solution. I mean, it's a good solution depending on the project requirements: mine allows using this solution.

---

**install package**

`pip install whitenoise`

**on wsgi.py I added:**

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

---

This way nginx site conf is ignored (but I think they had already ignored!)

[Django WhiteNoise documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitenoise)

> With a couple of lines of config WhiteNoise allows your web app to
>   serve its own static files, making it a self-contained unit that can
>   be deployed anywhere without relying on nginx, Amazon S3 or any other
>   external service. (Especially useful on Heroku, OpenShift and other
>   PaaS providers.)
>
> It’s designed to work nicely with a CDN for high-traffic sites so you
>   don’t have to sacrifice performance to benefit from simplicity.
>
> WhiteNoise works with any WSGI-compatible app but has some special
>   auto-configuration features for Django.
>
> WhiteNoise takes care of best-practices for you, for instance:
>
> Serving compressed content (gzip and Brotli formats, handling
>   Accept-Encoding and Vary headers correctly) Setting far-future cache
>   headers on content which won’t change Worried that serving static
>   files with Python is horribly inefficient? Still think you should be
>   using Amazon S3? Have a look at the Infrequently Asked Questions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the issue is two-fold:

1. It looks like you may have an error in your nginx config. Is `new_esmart/` really in your root directory`/` or is it somewhere like `/home/sam/new_esmart/`? If it is not in your root directory, make sure to provide the complete path.
2. It looks like your `STATIC_ROOT` will point to `path/to/new_esmart/static/` rather than `/new_esmart/esmart2/static/`. Keep in mind that `STATIC_ROOT` is the place where your static files will be copied to when you run `collectstatic` *not* the place you personally place static files when creating them initially.

So what you probably need to do is confirm that you really want your static files collected to `/actual/path/to/new_esmart/static/` and then use that same path in your nginx config.

Also, as discussed in the comments, you could try adding `listen 8001;` to your nginx config:

```
server {
    listen      8001;
    server_name 192.168.30.17;
    access_log off;
    ...
```

Comment: new_esmart/ is in my root directory and also if i print STATIC_ROOT I get /new_esmart/esmart2/static/ ... So the problem is not here I suppose

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that `new_esmart` was the project, and `esmrt2` was an app, but `emart2` is the project? Also, I assume you have `'django.contrib.admin'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @Sam also, try adding `listen 8001` to your nginx config on a the line before `server_name 192.168.30.17;`

Comment: Yes I've django.contrib.admin on INSTALLED_APPS and esmart2 is the app, not new_esmart. Also I found out that deleting nginx site-active symbolic link doesn't affect anything

Comment: @Sam did you try adding the `listen` line?

Comment: I can't right now. By the way I wrote a small update at the bottom of the question

Comment: @Sam OK, I am not sure, but I think that the settings are potentially being avoided *because* this line is missing. Worth a try at least.

Comment: @elethan is likely correct, as i've had the same issue. Try adding the listen port so your NGINX binds to gunicorn.

Comment: @elethan I've added "listen 8001"; to nginx config site but nothing changes. 

Just for avoiding doubts: deleting static files and then running "python manage collectstatic", files are copied in "/new_esmart/esmart2/static"